# Google Chrome extensions - Get images from cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am reprogramming a Google Chrome extension, it was able to download an image using the *src* attribute, but now, the page change the way it shows the image, it use in the *src* attribute some kind of script that in background changes the image, getting a different image that web page is showing. I can see the image that I need but using "ChromeCacheView" of NIRSOFT, but it's a desktop solution, so it can't help to do it in the Chrome extension.

Someone could help me, please!

This code below is what I'm using now, but as I said already, it can't show me the web page image is showing.

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // I think here is where I need the change Getting this ID from cache
    var kima = $(frame1).contents().find("#ccontrol1");
    xhr.open('GET',kima[0].src,true); 
    // 
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';

    xhr.onload = function(e) {
      if (this.status == 200) {
         var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: 'image/png'});
         kym_send_image(blob);
         kym_process01();
      }
    };

    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
        window.location.href = url1;
        return;
    };

    xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you need to use request.fetch,

You could replace your code with this one below

```
fetch(kima[0].src,{cache : "force-cache"}).then(r => r.blob({type: 'image/jpg'})).then(blob => function_to_catch_blob(blob));
```

Hope this could help you!